while using parseFloat , not able to calculate the amount more than 1 million
While using check box section in asp.net ,grid view,with the following code.
not able to calculate the sum of the amount ,
eg,

if the grid row having the value with 1,001,870.00 then,getting the
result as 1

if the grid row having the value with 976,000 then,
getting the result as 976,000


am using the following script function,
function GetSelected() {
    debugger;
    
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%=grvGroup.ClientID%>");

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var amountFC = 0;
    var amountVAT = 0;
    var amountSUMTOT = 0;
    var countSelect = 0;
    var totalValAmount = 0;
    
    if (grid.rows.length > 0) {

        for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
            var checkBoxes = grid.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
            var checkedid = checkBoxes[0].getAttribute('id');
            var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkedid);

            if (checkbox.checked) {
                Amt = grid.rows[i].cells[5].innerText.replace(",", "");
                amountFC += parseFloat(Amt);
                Amt = grid.rows[i].cells[6].innerText.replace(",", "");
                amountVAT += parseFloat(Amt);
                
                countSelect++;
            }
        }
        jQuery('#<%=txtTotalAmount.ClientID %>').val(amountFC);
        jQuery('#<%=txtTotalVat.ClientID %>').val(amountVAT);
        var totalAmount = parseFloat(jQuery('#<%=txtTotalAmount.ClientID %>').val());
        var totalVat = parseFloat(jQuery('#<%=txtTotalVat.ClientID %>').val());
        var totalSum = totalAmount + totalVat;


        jQuery('#<%=txtPayableAmount.ClientID %>').val(totalSum);

    }
    if (grid.rows.length - 1 == countSelect) {
        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_checkallselect").checked = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_checkallselect").checked = false;
    }
}


replace(",", "");  that will only replace 1 comma.  You could use replaceAll,. eg. a function like -> const asNum = v => parseFloat(v.replaceAll(",","")); might help.

In the documentation of JS function replace() we can read the following:

A string pattern will only be replaced once. To perform a global
search and replace, use a regular expression with the g flag, or use
replaceAll() instead.

These are the two options you have to remove all , from your number.
ReplaceAll()
grid.rows[i].cells[5].innerText.replaceAll(",", "");

Using REGEX
grid.rows[i].cells[5].innerText.replace(/,/g, "");

Docs
Replace
Replace all

the second is not worked for me, but the first one it works perfectly. and the sounds good for the answer , thanks for the support.

Please follow DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.
Best to create a polyfill on window object that named i.e. parseFloatFromString().
Put this code on load of your project.
For your case:
parseFloatFromString(grid.rows[i].cells[5].innerText);



// polyfill parseFloatFromString() now available in window object as parseFloat()

if(!('parseFloatFromString' in window)){
    Window.prototype.parseFloatFromString = function(numberInString){
        try {
            return +(numberInString.replaceAll(",", ""));
        } catch ( err ) { console.error(err) };
    }
}

console.log(parseFloatFromString('1,001,870.22'))



